# ZipStream and Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana

I'm trying to implement on the fly creating and streaming zip files in Kohana 3.3 using ZipStream (https://github.com/Grandt/PHPZip). I assumed that zip file would be streamed as soon as first image is added to zip, but it happens that download is stalled up until whole zip file is created and sent to user.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Download extends Controller {
    public function action_images()
    {
        require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'ZipStream');
        $zip = new ZipStream("images.zip");
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            $zip->addLargeFile($image);
        }
        $zip->finalize();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Kohana buffers output and that can be negated by adding this to download action.

```
while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Whole controller

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

    class Controller_Download extends Controller {
        public function action_images()
        {
            while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
                ob_end_clean();
            }
            require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'ZipStream');
            $zip = new ZipStream("images.zip");
            foreach($images as $image)
            {
                $zip->addLargeFile($image);
            }
            $zip->finalize();
            exit;
        }
    }
```